# " 'User' object has no attribute 'products' 'User' "

Tags: django

When I run my code I keep getting this error " 'User' object has no attribute 'products' 'User' " I don't know where I went wrong please help me. Below is are my user's app codes
Because I am trying to build the website to display products onto the user's profile page so the user can see the products they have got and also display these products on the main home page but I got stuck with this error. "'User' object has no attribute 'products'"

```
**View.py**


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'{username}! your account created')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    users = request.user
    products = users.products.all()
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'user': users, 'products': products})



@login_required
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.users = request.user
            product.slug = slugify(product.title)
            product.save()

            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    
    return render(request, 'users/add_product.html', {'form': form})
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**
This is my forms.py file in my users app

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from product.models import Product


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=300)
    postcode = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address', 'postcode', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'image', 'title', 'description', 'price']
```

**Product model**

This is the product model in my product app

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

from django.core.files import File
from django.db import models

from users.models import Users

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_thumbnail(self):
        if self.thumbnail:
            return self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            if self.image:
                self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
                self.save()

                return self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                return 'https://via.placeholder.com/240x180.jpg'
    
    def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
        img = Image.open(image)
        img.convert('RGB')
        img.thumbnail(size)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

        thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

        return thumbnail
```

Comment: Your `Users` model is likely *not* the user model, hence `request.user` is not a `Users` model, but a `User` model.

Comment: products = users.products.all()  // causing the error

Comment: Instead of redefine django's user model, create a profile table or create a custom model from AbstractUser,  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Try 
`products = Product.objects.all()`
`user = products.vendor`